# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'EmailAddress' not found on type com.iid.users.model.UsersPrimary

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I am new to spring,hibernate integration.

here are some code snippets and they are throwing javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException.

snippets are as follows

UsersPrimary.java

```
package com.iid.users.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Generated;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenerationTime;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Users_Primary")
public class UsersPrimary implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="Email_Address" ,unique=true , nullable=false ,length=30)
    private String EmailAddress;

    @Column(name="Password", nullable=false ,length=30)
    private String Password;

    @Column(name="First_Name", nullable=false ,length=30)
    private String FirstName;

    @Column(name="Last_Name", nullable=false ,length=30)
    private String LastName;

    @Column(name="Date_Of_Birth", nullable=false)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date DateOfBirth;

    @Column(name="Sex", nullable=false ,length=30)
    private String Sex;

    @Column(name="RoleName", nullable=false ,length=30)
    private String RoleName;


    @Column(name="Creation_Time", insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private Timestamp creationTime;

    @Column(name="is_Enabled", nullable=false ,length=30)
    private String isEnabled;


    @Column(name="Enable_Time",  insertable = false , columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private Timestamp Enable_Time  ;


    public UsersPrimary() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public UsersPrimary(String emailAddress, String password, String firstName, String lastName, Date dateOfBirth, String sex, String roleName, Timestamp creationTime, String isEnabled, Timestamp enable_Time) {
        super();
        EmailAddress = emailAddress;
        Password = password;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        Sex = sex;
        RoleName = roleName;
        this.creationTime = creationTime;
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
        Enable_Time = enable_Time;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return EmailAddress;
    }


    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        EmailAddress = emailAddress;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }


    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }


    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }


    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }


    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }


    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return DateOfBirth;
    }


    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }


    public String getSex() {
        return Sex;
    }


    public void setSex(String sex) {
        Sex = sex;
    }


    public String getRoleName() {
        return RoleName;
    }


    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        RoleName = roleName;
    }


    public Timestamp getCreationTime() {
        return creationTime;
    }


    public void setCreationTime(Timestamp creationTime) {
        this.creationTime = creationTime;
    }


    public String getIsEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }


    public void setIsEnabled(String isEnabled) {
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    }


    public Timestamp getEnable_Time() {
        return Enable_Time;
    }


    public void setEnable_Time(Timestamp enable_Time) {
        Enable_Time = enable_Time;
    }


}
```

below is snippet of controller method of controller class

SearchController.java

```
    private UsersPrimaryService ups ;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView search(@RequestParam(value="SearchField")String SearchField,HttpSession sessionObj, HttpServletRequest req) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        System.out.println(SearchField);
        sessionObj.setAttribute("searchResultList" , ups.searchUsersPrimaryList(SearchField));
        model.setViewName("/WEB-INF/jsp/Search/searchResult");
        return model;
    }
```

and below is the snippet from the searchResult.jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${searchResultList}" var="UsersPrimary">

<a href="#">  <c:out value="${UsersPrimary.EmailAddress}"></c:out>  <c:out value="${UsersPrimary.FirstName}"></c:out> <c:out value="${UsersPrimary.LastName}"></c:out> </a>

</c:forEach>
```

everytime i am running the code gettting

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'EmailAddress' not found on type com.iid.users.model.UsersPrimary
```

dont know why ? i am using spring 4.1.1 and hibernate 4.3.6. .

is that some kind of bug or my snippets are wrong ?

Comment: What's your getter name? Fields should be started from lowercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the getter for `EmailAddress` field called `getEmailAddress()`? It's probably an issue with upper/lower case field names. Generally, field names should start with lower case letter (so `emailAddress` instead of `EmailAddress`), it is a globally accepted convention and a lot of frameworks depend on it while using reflection.

While it may be a major refactoring for you, you should change your fields to be [lowerCamelCase](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/lowerCamelCase) and in your particular case with the getter named `getEmailAddress()` it should work.

As a quick workaround, try changing the expression to `<c:out value="${UsersPrimary.getEmailAddress()}"></c:out>`.

Comment: As simple as that. :)